# Current date in SAP HANA and difference between dates

Tags: hana

I am trying to write a small SQL statement in HANA Studio in scripted calculation view .

The example data set is as below:

[image]

I want to select all the ships that are departing five days from prior today (4th December, 2017) and after today.

The output should be

```
  B           09/12/2017
  D           29/12/2017
```

What is the SQL function that I should use and how to figure out todays date in HANA studio and as well as the difference between today's date and date in each record?

**UPDATE 1**

```
SHIP_NAME   DATE_OF_DEPARTURE(DD/MM/YYYY)
   A           15/12/2017
   B           09/12/2017
   c           30/12/2017
   D           29/12/2017
```

Can anybody figure out any issues with this statement? It's not working.

```sql
SELECT T1."SHIP_NAME" AS "Ship Name" , 
DAYS_BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE,T1."DATE_OF_DEPARTURE") AS "Days Between" 
FROM "_SYS_BI"."M_SHIP_DEPARTURE" as T1;
```

@Lars Br.  a little help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> use the documentation, Luke! 
>   :)

If you did, you’d find that the`current_date` gives you the, well, current date.